# Unexpected message when painting PyQt widget background

Tags: python, pyqt

Why I'm getting this message `QPainter::begin: Painter already active` in the console when I run this code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
import sys


class MyRoundWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super(MyRoundWidget,self).__init__(master)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowTitle("QLinearGradient Vertical Gradient ")
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)        

    def paintEvent(self, ev):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.begin(self)
        gradient = QLinearGradient(QRectF(self.rect()).topLeft(),QRectF(self.rect()).bottomLeft())
        gradient.setColorAt(0.0, Qt.black)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.4, Qt.gray)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.7, Qt.black)
        painter.setBrush(gradient)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 10.0, 10.0)
        painter.end()


def main():    
    app     = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyRoundWidget()    
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def paintEvent(self, ev):
    painter = QPainter(self)
    gradient = QLinearGradient(QRectF(self.rect()).topLeft(),QRectF(self.rect()).bottomLeft())
    gradient.setColorAt(0.0, Qt.black)
    gradient.setColorAt(0.4, Qt.gray)
    gradient.setColorAt(0.7, Qt.black)
    painter.setBrush(gradient)
    painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 10.0, 10.0)
```

Remove `painter.begin(self)` and `painter.end()`.

According to the [Qt docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#begin):

> Note that most of the time, you can use one of the constructors
>   instead of begin(), and that end() is automatically done at
>   destruction.
>
> Warning: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.

So, if you use `painter = QPainter(self)` to construct a painter, then it will be unnecessary to call `begin()` and `end()`. This will be duplicated.